# backend/config/main.php ->assetManager -> baseUrl

Tags: php, yii

I'm following the method described [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/33/organize-directories-for-applications-with-front-end-and-back-end) to have my control panel in backend folder.

The problem is I don't want to create two assets folders so I want to set assetManager baseUrl property in my backend/config/main.php but I'm enable to get the URL of the backend in the config. I don't want it hard coded because I need the code to be portable.

What can I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure asset manager's baseUrl in /backend/config/main.php

```
    'components' => array(

    ...

    'assetManager' => array(
        'class' => 'CAssetManager',
        'baseUrl' => 'frontend.assets'
    ),

    ...
```